# Unable to deploy Keycloak (9.0.0) deployment on Minishift (1.34.0): keycloak-add-user.json (Permission denied)

Tags: openshift, keycloak, minishift

I am unable to launch **Keycloak** (9.0.0) on **Minishift** (v1.34.0+f5db7cb) and getting ***Crash loop back off*** error. This Deployment will be integrated with a Postgres deployment.

Keycloak Pod logs:

> /opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/keycloak-add-user.json (Permission denied)

Here is the yaml file which I deployed through the console (`oc apply -f`):

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert
    kompose.version: 1.16.0 (0c01309)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: keycloak
  name: keycloak
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      io.kompose.service: keycloak
  replicas: 1
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: keycloak
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: DB_ADDR
          value: postgres
        - name: DB_DATABASE
          value: keycloak
        - name: DB_PASSWORD
          value: password
        - name: DB_SCHEMA
          value: public
        - name: DB_USER
          value: keycloak
        - name: DB_VENDOR
          value: POSTGRES
        - name: KEYCLOAK_LOGLEVEL
          value: DEBUG
        - name: KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD
          value: Pa55w0rd
        - name: KEYCLOAK_USER
          value: admin
        image: localhost:5000/keycloak
        name: keycloak
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        - containerPort: 8443
        resources: {}
      restartPolicy: Always
status: {}

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert
    kompose.version: 1.16.0 (0c01309)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: keycloak
  name: keycloak
spec:
  ports:
  - name: "8880"
    port: 8880
    targetPort: 8080
  - name: "8888"
    port: 8888
    targetPort: 8443
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    io.kompose.service: keycloak
```

Is there any way to resolve this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`keycloak-add-user.json` is generated by `KEYCLOAK_HOME/bin/add-user-keycloak.sh` utility. Keycloak server on startup checks presence of this file and if found specified user will be added.

In its turn Keycloak pod during startup resolve whether there is an variables for user creation like `KEYCLOAK_USER` and `KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD`, and if they exist, `add-user-keycloak.sh` utility would be called with those params to create user.

So in your case you should make `/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration` directory writable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried adding a `chmod -R 775` command to `/opt/jboss/keycloak` but I'm getting "no such file or directory". Any suggestions on how to change the directory access permissions?

Comment: I don't have any knowledge about opehshift/minshift. Is your deployment config use some of official keycloak docker images? If so, try to check keycloak-container github repo for bootstrapping details.